# pip list shows installed module but still getting import error

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am working with python flask's requests module. I have installed requests module using :

```
pip install requests
```

And verified that requests module exists when I run :

```
pip list
```

But when I run my python application , I receive import Error for requests module.

I noticed that pip is installing the module in `C:\Users\xx\Documents\Projects\Python\Python3REST\lib\site-packages\` folder BUT  the interpreter is looking for the module in `C:\Users\xx\Documents\Projects\Python\Python3REST\lib\site-packages\flask\` folder.

I have tried running the command :

```
pip install --install-option="Path to install in" requests
```

But threw some other error.

The import error I am getting states :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'requests' from 'flask'
(C:\Users\xx\Documents\Projects\Python\Python3REST\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py)
```

I am working in virtualenv in Windows 10.

Comment: What is your python path? It sounds like your python path doesn't match up with your site-packages and your interpreter can't find modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you add that folder to your path? using sys.path.extend?

Answer (score 11):

I recently had the same problem installing a self made package. I installed it with `pip install <package>` and checked it was actually installed with `pip list` but running the script with  `import <package>` returned a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <package>`.

I solved the problem creating an empty file called `__init__.py` in the package directory.

Check [https://pythontips.com/2013/07/28/what-is-**init**-py/](https://pythontips.com/2013/07/28/what-is-__init__-py/) and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages for better understanding.

Comment: I read somewhere that from Python 3.6+ we wouldn't need the `__init__.py` files anymore. It is strange that that file is still necessary only at the custom module's root, but not within subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `python3 -m pip install <package name>`. In the OP's case, it should be `python3 -m pip install requests`.

Note that I'm using python 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Check that the folder that your code is in, is not named 'flask' or has some other conflicting name.