# Module installs but doesn't import

Tags: python, pip, pythonpath

I'm on an OS Catalina and I'm trying to install and run Mephisto (see https://github.com/facebookresearch/mephisto/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md). I created a python3 virtual environment and then went to the directory and ran

`sudo pip3 install -e .`

This seems to have run fine as I can now run `mephisto` and see the list of commands and options. However when I run `mephisto register mturk` it throws `No module named 'mephisto.core.argparse_parser'` because of an import statement in the python file. This seems like a general issue of a module installing but not importing the module properly, but would appreciate help in how to fix it. Is it because my $PYTHONPATH is currently empty?

Answer (score 1):

Mephisto Lead here! This seems to have been a case of unfortunate timing, as we were in the midst of a refactor there and some code got pushed to master that should've received more scrutiny. We'll be moving to stable releases via PyPI in the near future to prevent things like this!

Answer (score 0):

> I created a python3 virtual environment and then went to the directory and ran
>
> `sudo pip3 install -e .`

You should not have used *sudo* to install this library, if you meant to install it in a virtual environment. By using *sudo* the library probably got installed in the global environment (not in the virtual environment).

Typically:

- create a virtual environment:

  - `python3 -m venv path/to/venv`
- install tools and libraries in this environment with:

  - `path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip install Mephisto`
- use python in the virtual environment:

  - `path/to/venv/bin/python -c 'import mephisto'`
- use a tool in the virtual environment:

  - `path/to/venv/bin/mephisto`

> Is it because my $PYTHONPATH is currently empty?

Forget `PYTHONPATH`. Basically one should never have to modify this environment variable (this is almost always ill-informed advice to get `PYTHONPATH` involved).

Comment: Thanks! However, it still seems like its not importing?

Command: ```path/to/venv/bin/mephisto register mturk```
Output: ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mephisto.core.argparse_parser'```

Comment: "_(Note: if you haven't set up mephisto with poetry, you should replace the mephisto command with python mephisto/client/cli.py instead)_" -- https://github.com/facebookresearch/mephisto/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md#step-2-run-the-same-task-again-but-now-on-mturk

Comment: Yes, I tried that too and it gives the same issue.

Comment: What is the output of `path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip show -v --files mephisto`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `__init__.py` file is in the module's file directory. If not try creating an empty one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56861605/pip-list-shows-installed-module-but-still-getting-import-error/59633953#59633953